# Releasing Memory in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, uibutton

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc]init];
```

In the above code, I should release btn because i know i have alloc them and later i need to perform
    `[btn release];` some where.

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonwithtype:UIButtonTypeRoundrect];
```

In the second type should i release btn or is btn an autoreleased object which i dont have to call release itself ?

How to release the btn in the second type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid thinking about whether objects are autoreleased or not. In actuality, many objects returned from convenience methods are not autoreleased at all, they could be static instances for example.

Instead, just think about whether you *own* the object or not. For methods that have `alloc`, `new`, or `copy` in the name—or for objects that you have explicitly obtained ownership of with `retain`—these imply that you *own* the returned object, and that you have to relinquish your ownership with `release`. For objects that you don't own, you don't have to `release` them.

The [rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) of memory management are *very* simple. Commit them to memory and the answers to questions like this will become second nature.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to release your button in second example; `[UIButton buttonWithType:]` returns an autoreleased object.

There is a simple rule: you need to `release` only when you `alloc`, `retain`, `copy` or `mutableCopy`.

Comment: Apple have mentioned that it is not beneficial to think about whether objects are autoreleased or not, only whether you own the object. As I mentioned in my own answer, many convenience methods don't return autoreleased objects but are still objects that you don't own.

Comment: See the top of page 14 of [this PDF](http://www.apple.com.cn/developer/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

In the second type  it returns an autorelease object , so you dont have to worry about releasing it.

Answer (score 0):

**First case:**

You have to release it because you own it.

- When you create an object(new or alloc, copy or mutablecopy), it has
  a retain count of 1 and you own it.
- When you send an object a retain message, its retain count is
  incremented by 1 and you own it.

**Second case:**

The button you receive is obtained from an convenience constructor.

The “convenience constructor” creates an object that is sent an autorelease message.

So you should not release the button in you second case. You could send a release message only if you have sent a retain method.

Comment: You are discussing a number of implementation details that are not necessarily true or relevant to this question. An autorelease pool might drain faster than before the end of the current event loop if a new autorelease pool is created manually (for the purposes of managing memory in a tight loop). You shouldn't care when an object will be released, you should instead think about whether you own the object or not.

Answer (score 0):

At second time, you dont need to release the button, it automatically return autorelease type. And You only require the object to release when you own it (like with alloc or new or copy).